How to delete a file as long as another file with the same name but a different extension of it exists?
So I want to free up space in my SSD, and then I saw my gigantic folder of OBS recordings.
A lot of them, have been remuxed from mkv to mp4. I want to delete the mkv ones, and keep the mp4 ones.
At first I thought of doing rm *.mkv, but then I remembered that there are some that have not been remuxed, and thus have remained at being mkv files. And I want to keep those.
So basically, my goal is to delete every mkv file, as long as another file with the exact same name but with a different file extension exists. I also am aware of the fact that the extension is the name on Linux, but considering the fact that in my use case there are only mp4 and mkv files, I suppose we can just count the last three letters. But I'd like a more robust option. I also don't care about subdirectories, as there are none in my use case.
I googled this, and after scrolling down a lot, I found this: Delete files if condition is met
And the answer suggests this:

for file in `find -type f -size +1000000k -name "*.mkv"`; do
  # This would remove the mkv extension
  noext=${file::-4}

  # Parts of directories
  parentdir=`echo $file | cut -d'/' -f2` # This would return 'Directories'

  if [ -e "./$parentdir/$noext.rar" ]; then
     rm -f "./$parentdir/$noext.rar"
  fi
done

I stared at this for a while but I genuinely couldn't figure out how to change it for my needs. I know pretty much nothing about bash.
Also, if you want examples (list of files before and after going through the command(s) needed), here you go (I also put a star "*" after each file that should be deleted for your convenience):
Input::
2022-13-64.mp4  (mkv exists, no operation done)
2022-13-64.mkv* (deleted, mp4 exists)
2025-01-35.mp4  (mkv exists, no operation done)
2025-01-35.mkv* (deleted, mp4 exists)
2027-08-12.mp4  (no mkv, no operation done)
2004-06-01.mkv  (is mkv, but no mp4 exists, no operation done)

Expected Output:
2022-13-64.mp4
2025-01-35.mp4
2027-08-12.mp4
2004-06-01.mkv

Also, keeping the mp4 is higher priority than keeping the mkv. For example if two files with the same "name" (as in, everything before mp4 or mkv) existed, but one was an mp4 and the other was an mkv, the mkv would be deleted and the mp4 would be kept. But sometimes, this is not wanted. For example sometimes only an mkv exists, and no mp4 of the same "name". In that case no deletion would be done on that file.

(1) Must, may or mustn't the solution work in subdirectories? (2) The -r in rm -r only matters if the operand is a directory. You did think about -r. Does this mean that some directories match *.mkv and the solution should remove them conditionally like regular files? (3) Any question should show reasonable research effort. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

(4) Also please clarify "another file with the exact same name but with a mp4 extension". The point is Linux does not use extensions natively like Windows does, therefore e.g. in case of foo.mkv foo is not a name and mkv is not an extension, the whole foo.mkv is the name. Now "the exact same name but with a mp4 extension" may mean foo.mp4 (changed extension, according to the Windows meaning of "extension") or foo.mkv.mp4 (extended name, according to the Linux meaning of "name"). Which one should be considered? Both?

@KamilMaciorowski Sorry for the vagueness in the question, I'm new to the site. I edited the question, hopefully you can understand it better now. And as for the removal of -r from rm in the edit, the reason why it was even there in the first place was literally because I misunderstood what -r did.

The script you found is flawed, read my comment there and do not go this way. Finding it was a valid research effort nevertheless. Yes, the question is quite clear now, I have voted to reopen. Few more votes are needed and hopefully fellow users will cast them soon.

@KamilMaciorowski Thanks! And also, is deleting a closed question and then making a new one to bypass the closure of the original against the rules? What if an edit was done to it? Is that against the rules too?

Such act is frowned upon, but in practice you may get away with this (I've seen this happen). Possible consequences: (1) I believe a question closed as unclear counts towards the question ban. I believe a question closed and self-deleted counts twice. I believe a formerly closed question that has been improved and thus reopened is considered not-so-bad and no longer counts towards the ban. I believe one question alone will not give you the ban, but if you ever ask poor question(s) in the future then the status of this one may make the difference.

(2) I will notice. Right now I'm willing to answer your question when it gets reopened. If you try to bypass the closure then I will reconsider and I may be not so eager. I'm speaking for myself; other users may or may not notice, may or may not care, so you may get answer(s) anyway. My advice is: wait at least 24 hours, then decide. The question was closed by a single moderator (I mean: not by multiple votes from several users), the moderator is quite active and AFAIK he reopens improved questions just fine. And there are others. But we all do sleep, do work etc. Just give us some time.

@KamilMaciorowski No no no no no, I was not going to delete and recreate it. I just wanted to know if it would be fine or not. Thanks for the explanation!

This portable snippet of shell code will process files in the current working directory (but not in subdirectories):
for f in ./*.mkv; do
   [ -f "${f%.mkv}.mp4" ] && echo rm "$f"
done

Just in case, the above is a dry run, it only prints what it would do. If this looks fine, remove exactly the string echo  to "arm" the snippet, then run the altered version.
The code loops over pathnames resulting from the expansion of the pattern ./*.mkv. Inside the loop $f (which should be properly quoted) expands to the currently processed pathname; ${f%.mkv} expands to the pathname with .mkv removed from the end; ${f%.mkv}.mp4 expands to the pathname with .mkv removed and then .mp4 added (concatenated). [ -f … ] tests if it's an existing regular file and && runs the next command (echo … in this case) if and only if the preceding one (i.e. our test) succeeds.
Note the standard is ./*.mkv does not match dotfiles. In Bash, if you want our snippet to match also dotfiles, invoke shopt -s dotglob beforehand. For completeness: shopt -u dotglob sets the standard behavior.

Thanks, it worked! But could you please explain more about how it works? I want to learn bash. (by the way, sorry I took so long to accept the answer)

@BOplaid Added terse explanation with useful links.
